# Keynote keyboard shortcut to navigate between objects on a slide

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keynote

If I am typing in the Title box and I want to keep my hands on the keyboard, is there a shortcut for me to navigate to the next text box or bulleted list (or whatever) on the screen without having to use my mouse?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate between text boxes on keynote without using your mouse and only keyboard by using the tab key. This has its limitation as it does not let you edit existing text but instead replace the text with what you begin texting. The process is as follows:

1. New Slide
2. Press Tab (bounding box highlights for the text box)
3. Start Typing (finish text)
4. Press Escape
5. Press Tab (continuing pressing to cycle)